# How to set full control for everyone on whole disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I'm running into problems with my external hard disk because of file permissions.

When I'm at school or work I cannot read all folders/files on the disk. The folders which I cannot reach are mostly the same (Folder /muziek isn't reachable at all, and some portable programs are failing because they cannot reach resources)

Is there any possibility to give the whole disk full permissions for everyone?
Or is there a more convenient solution for this problem?

Thanks Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening cmd as admin and running the following command on a folder should give full access rights to users.

```
icacls "X:\muziek" /grant Users:F /T
```

This will also affect all subfolders/subfiles.
To view permissions on a folder/file use:

```
icacls "X:\Path\To\Folder\or\File.ext"
```

Edit: feel free to play around with "icacls" (run "icacls /h" for help), but be wary of using it on systemfolders.